# Create and remove a form_tag with JavaScript in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to figure out how to add `form_tag`s to my page dynamically with JavaScript. I can probably figure out how to add regular forms, but I would prefer adding form_tags so I can get the handy "authenticity_token" when the form is submitted.
Here is my view...

show.html.erb:

```
<button id="add-new-form">Add invite</button>

<div class="invite-user-forms">
 <%= form_tag("/contests/#{@contest.id}", remote: true, class: "invite-user", controller: "contestants", action: "create", method: "post") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:emailVal) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Send invitation") %>
    <%= button_tag("Remove") %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And here is my outline for my JavaScript expectation, though I don't know how to add a form_tag...
application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#add-new-form").click(function(){
    $(".invite-user-forms").append("form_tag??");
  });
});
```

Furthermore, I'd like to remove the form_tag by clicking the "Remove" `button_tag`...I assume each new form would need a unique ID in order for this to work, though...so perhaps my JavaScript would look like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#remove-button-(some unique value)").click(function(){
    $("#unique-form-value").remove();
  });
});
```

Any advice is gladly appreciated.

Comment: By "dynamically" with JS, what do you mean? That each time a new form is created, a record of that form exists in the DB as well? Or show the form in a modal-popup or? I'm not quite following the question... If you want true dynamics, you need to make use of the RESTful API that rails provides and create a model for your forms with a has_many relation.

Comment: Hi Crashtor...As for the DBs, I've already created a "has_many" relationship between "contests" and "contestants". So this form is basically for creating new contestants. However, it's a bit complicated because the email value that the form submits will either go to the "contestants" table or an "invitations" staging table, depending on whether or not the given email address matches one in the "users" table...and that logic of determining which table to go to is handled in the controller.

Comment: Ok, I see - Then you need to make use of Ajax for adding and removing the forms.

Comment: Is there a way to make use of the "authenticity_token" when creating these forms via JS?

Comment: Yes, of course - You need to load the forms in a partial using ajax - I'm scrabbling it together as we speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To point you in the right direction:

```
<%= form_for Contestants.new, remote: true do |f| %>
<%= f.button :submit, "create new contestant" %>
<% end %>
```

And below, you need to loop through all the forms that have been created.

```
<%= @contestants.each do %>
    <div class="invite-user-forms">
         <%= form_tag("/contests/#{@contest.id}", remote: true, class: "invite-user", controller: "contestants", action: "create", method: "post") do %>
        <%= text_field_tag(:emailVal) %>
        <%= submit_tag("Send invitation") %>
        <%= button_tag("Remove"), remote: true, method: :delete %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

However, right now - you're not actually creating a new contestant, it has already been created, when you hit the button above - Also, when creating an entry it can't be empty (It can't be just a submit button, like I showed you above, so preferably you could put something in a <%= f.hidden_field). Right now, you're editing a contestant, so this form needs to be under the edit action. This form also needs **'remote: true'**

If you're uncertain about the workings of remote: true and Ajax with rails, just google 'remote: true rails' and suck up any information you can get your hands on - **there's loads.**

Comment: Thank you @Crashtor. This is starting to click for me, though I'm getting an error in the first line. I assume it should be Contestant.new (singular)...so I changed that but I'm still getting an error. Is there supposed to be the `@` identifier in the `form_for`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad - form_for Contestant.new.

Comment: Ok this got me on the right track; I'll mark it as correct.